# org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized

Tags: java, sharepoint, cmis

-I am getting Exception with STANDARD_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
while createSession.

-previously it was working fine but suddenly stopped working,Also NTLM is working fine in my case.

-Also when once authenticated with NTLM and if changing to Basic again Session is getting generated but while retrieving folder details are Unauthorized.

-CMIS producer is Active at Sharepoint repo end.

```
parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS, CmisBindingFactory.STANDARD_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER);
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:477)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:645)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:808)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfo(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfo(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.connect(SessionImpl.java:1051)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.createSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.createSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.dms.externaldriver.cmisdriver.interfaceimpl.DMSClientInterfaceImpl.getSession(DMSClientInterfaceImpl.java:193)
    at com.dms.externaldriver.cmisdriver.interfaceimpl.DMSClientInterfaceImpl.<init>(DMSClientInterfaceImpl.java:148)
    at com.dms.driver.action.DMSExternalAction.getDMSExternalListTreeXML(DMSExternalAction.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:401)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:399)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
```

Comment: If someone going through the question , help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question as it is resolved now.

Re-entered the credential on server end and server was restarted.